# Importing a PostGIS and a Delimited Text layer in QGIS, not overlapping

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm a beginner in QGIS, and I have a PostGIS database and a CSV file I would like to visualize.
I followed the instructions in [this question and the answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13710/why-dont-different-layers-overlap-in-quantum-gis), but it doesn't work for me, my two layers are still not overlapping.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. I create a new project, and in the project properties, in CRS, I "enable 'on the fly' CRS transofrmation" and select "Google Mercator".
2. I add a PostGIS layer. In the "Properties" ("General") of this layer, the specified layer is "EPSG:900913 - Google Mercator". In "Metadata", I have:

   > +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
3. Finally, I add a Delimited Text layer. This one is in Swiss Coordinates, so when adding it, Google Mercator is proposed, but I change it to "CH1903+". In "Metadata", I have:

   > +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

I'm choosing Google Mercator because when I first added the PostGIS layer, it was automatically selected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are examples of data from my sets:
CSV (Swiss coordinates):

> 533288    152585
>
> 533230    152625
>
> 533066    152647
>
> 533057    152660
>
> 533110    152607
>
> 533143    152627
>
> 533162    152571
>
> 533103    152560

PostGIS (Google Mercator coordinates) (supposedly overlapping more or less):

> 731632.384716794;5863923.31681192
>
> 731351.09395362;5864059.81606372
>
> 731351.452782778;5864091.19255148
>
> 731202.814656544;5864134.45924451
>
> 731322.906745951;5864210.56763595
>
> 731128.278515869;5864216.17023219
>
> 731337.333643971;5864149.17870271
>
> 730796.011530197;5864247.06311145
>
> 731613.06159501;5864003.29715222
>
> 730454.864224799;5863712.64413468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you picked the wrong Swiss CRS.

**EPSG:21781 - CH1903 / LV03** looks good to me.

Comment: I'm feeling so stupid. Thank you so much for your answer!